# Postfix operator //, when to use it

Tags: coding-style

The postfix operator // seems more legible when applying formatting functions or functions that provide general information about an object, like Length does.

Is it acceptable to use it in those cases?

Example code:

```
StringJoin[
  "Elements in Range ", n // ToString , " to ", nMax // ToString, ". Length: ", 
  Block[{}, flast = f] // Length // ToString, "."]
```

Or should i stick to using `ToString[Length[...]]`? This seems like "Yodaspeak" without the actual advantages of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "acceptable"? whether it works? or whether it's a recommended practice (say, for the sake of readability)?

Comment: I think that this is very subjective and up to you.  Personally, I would lean towards not doing this, at least not without matching line breaks and indentation.  But it's really only about readability, and readability also depends on what you are used to (i.e. it's not entirely universal).  So just do what you like.

Comment: There is no clear-cut answer. It is a matter of which style you find clearer and makes the code easier to maintain.

Comment: BTW I think that `ToString@Length[...]` is objectively better than `ToString[Length[...]]` because it reduces the number of brackets that one needs to visually match up.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I mean whether it's Recommended practice.

Comment: @Szabolcs Your ToString@ seems way better. The bracket thing was one of the reasons i found // better.

Comment: @Szabolcs just use `ToString@*Length@...` and you need no brackets at all :-D

Comment: Yes, some people like `ToString@Length@x`, some others like `ToString@Length[x]`. I think that this is again entirely subjective. (I like the second, but there's no rational reason I can bring up. Perhaps it's just habit.)  `ToString @* Length @ x` is not quite equivalent ... though it *usually* has the same effect.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think ToString@(value) is better since it optically differentiates formatting functions and functions which actually do something to value like Length does.

Comment: I like the postfix notation as a convenient way to build an expression incrementally.  After each evaluation, I can add a step with a minimum of cursor movement.